# Can Expresso Store pass billing details to Worldpay?

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce, worldpay

Is it possible for Expresso Store to pass billing details on to Worldpay so the buyer doesn't have to add them again?

Comment: Looking at the [code](https://github.com/expressodev/ci-merchant/blob/develop/libraries/merchant/merchant_worldpay.php), it should already be doing so. Is it passing any details through? What versions are you running?

Comment: Sorry, that was weird - it's working now. It wasn't before but now it is. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, it looks like it can:
https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#worldpay